# ListView reloading error if one of the records is selected priorly

Tags: c#, listview, uwp, selecteditem, selecteditemchanged

I have a ListView that pulls data from a database via class.

I also use listView_SelectionChanged to track the name of selected product.

```
 public void listView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        var selected = LstView.SelectedItem as Product;

            string prodName = selected.ProductId.ToString();
            SelectedProductName.Text = prodName;



    }
```

As you can see, when row of the ListView is selected, I pull the ProductId, store it in string prodName and then assign it to TextBlock SelectedProductName. 
At this point, when I hit Go! button to RELOAD same list, I get error on line:

```
 string prodName = selected.ProductId.ToString();
```

That says:
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: When you reload the list, the selected item changes to null as nothing is selected anymore.  This is causing your variable 'selected' to be null, and you cannot access properties/methods of null classes.  Think of it this way.  You buy a car (your list), you install a new touch screen radio (you selected an item), you sell the car and buy a new one (you clicked the button that reloads the list), then you are trying to change the station on the radio of your old car

Comment: Yes. I imagined that is the problem. But I cannot think of a simple solution to this problem. Should I change the textBlock's assignment on the list reload to something temporary?

Comment: That, or you could wrap the logic after setting the 'selected' variable in a null check:
if (selected != null)
{
    SelectedProductName.Text = selected.ProductId.ToString();
}
else
{
    SelectedProductName.Text = "Default product name";
}

Comment: @elhs16 That is very nice. It works obviously. Sometimes the simplest is the hardest to see. Thank you very much elhs16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is in the comments, this is posted for future devs who stumble upon this question.

The Problem:
When you reload the list, the selected item changes to null as nothing is selected anymore. This is causing your variable 'selected' to be null, and you cannot access properties/methods of null classes. Think of it this way. You buy a car (your list), you install a new touch screen radio (you selected an item), you sell the car and buy a new one (you clicked the button that reloads the list), then you are trying to change the station on the radio of your old car

The Solution:

```
public void listView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var selected = LstView.SelectedItem as Product;

    if (selected != null)
    {
        SelectedProductName.Text = selected.ProductId.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        SelectedProductName.Text = "Default Product Name";
    }
}
```